# Bash Coding Errors

Tags: javascript, linux, bash, ubuntu

My Bash code runs fine when executed in terminal, but when I execute from a js file. It gives me the following error:

```
root@ChrisAlienWare:~/node_modules/Chris# sudo node index.js
/home/chris/node_modules/bat.sh:2
curl -X POST \
        ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The Code for the Trigger is

```
var config = require('./config');
var dash_button = require('node-dash-button');

var dash = dash_button(config.dash.MAC_address);

dash.on('detected', function (){
var spawn = require('bat.sh').spawn;

});
```

**Code:**

```
!/bin/sh

curl -X POST \
  --data-urlencode 'payload={"text": "This is Dash.", "channel": "#water-cooler", "username": "MrBot", "icon_emoji": ":neckbeard:"}' \
  https://hooks.slack.com/services/#############################
```

If someone could explain, that would be great.

Comment: what has this got to do with java?

Comment: @ScaryWombat The programming language used has a similar-sounding name. I removed the tag

Answer (score 1):

You can't `require` a shell script in node.js.

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html says how to execute another program.

Node.js can make HTTP requests without an external program. In this example, I'm using the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) library.

```
var request = require('request');
request.post('https://hooks.slack.com/services/#############################',
    {form: {payload:'{"text": "This is Dash.", "channel": "#water-cooler", "username": "MrBot", "icon_emoji": ":neckbeard:"}'}},
    function (error, response, body) {
        //do something
    });
```

Comment: Didn't work. Can you give me a block for starting it a different way?